# Getting 1's and 0's instead of COUNT in this query

Tags: sql

In my dataset, I'm trying to find how many Stores have had at least 10 events where the value of each event was greater than $100.

[image: Here are my tables]

```
SELECT COUNT(EventId) >=10
FROM Event 
WHERE Event.EventValue >100
GROUP BY Site.SiteName
```

I appear to just be getting 1's and 0's instead of getting the `site names` that fit this criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work in your case.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM (
      SELECT COUNT(EventId) AS T
      FROM Event 
      WHERE Event.EventValue >100
      GROUP BY Site.SiteName
) DATA
```

Comment: So I can understand this properly, this is a case statement where it's counting wildcards of any unique row based on the site name?

Comment: Right. Doesn't matter using `COUNT(*)`or `COUNT(T)`. We' ve created new virtual table as `DATA` and it includes only unique `SiteName` field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            eventid
        FROM
            events
        WHERE
            eventvalue > 100
        GROUP BY
            eventid
        HAVING
            COUNT(1) >= 10
    )
```

Comment: Hi @jeiv, your query will return number of row, not 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is returning 0 and 1 to mean FALSE and TRUE, because your SELECT clause is asking whether the COUNT(EventId) is greater than 10. Instead, try selecting the SiteId and putting your COUNT > 10 criterion in a HAVING clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
select Site.SiteId, Site.SiteName
from (select SiteId, count(distinct EventId)
from Event 
where EventValue > 100
group by SiteId
having count(distinct EventId) >= 10
) EV
join Site 
on EV.SiteId = Site.SiteId
;
```

Answer (score 0):

1/0 are the answer as it is showing True/False as your SELECT cause is asking for the count greater than 10 not the name. It should work if you ask for the SiteID and look at count >10 as it will show names not a true false answer.